# Postgres query plan - why hash join, not nested loop?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I've got postgres 11. And trying to execute query:

```sql
SELECT t.row_id,
       t.calc_id,
       t.load_id,
       f.fact_value metric_value
FROM   vw_f_tasks t
       LEFT JOIN vw_f_devs f
              ON ( f.row_id = t.calc_id
                   AND f.load_id = t.load_id )
WHERE  t.row_id IN ( '1066677788', '1066677789' );
```

1. Here is DDL of view - vw_f_tasks:

```sql
CREATE OR replace VIEW vw_f_tasks
AS
  SELECT f_tasks.row_id,
         f_tasks.calc_id,
         f_tasks.load_id,
         lib_dev.direction_id AS alg_direction_id
  FROM   f_tasks
         left join isu_lib_deviations lib_dev
                ON lib_dev.dev_type_id = "Substring"(f_tasks.load_id :: text,
                                         '([0-9]+)' :: text)
                                         :: bigint;
```

DDL of tables, from which view is made

```sql
CREATE TABLE f_tasks
  (
     row_id  VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
     calc_id VARCHAR(500) NULL,
     load_id VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT f_tasks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (row_id)
  );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX f_tasks_pkey ON f_tasks USING btree (row_id) CREATE INDEX
ib_f_tasks_load_id ON f_tasks USING btree (load_id) CREATE TABLE
isu_lib_deviations ( algorithm_id INT4 NOT NULL, dev_type_id INT8 NOT NULL,
direction_id NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT core_deviations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (algorithm_id
) );

CREATE INDEX isu_lib_deviations_dev_type_id_idx ON isu_lib_deviations USING
btree (dev_type_id)
```

2. Second view - vw_f_devs:

```sql
CREATE OR replace VIEW dm_core.vw_f_devs ASSELECT    f_devs.row_id,
          f_devs.load_id,
          f_devs.fact_value,
          lib_dev.direction_id AS alg_direction_id
FROM      f_devs
LEFT JOIN isu_lib_deviations lib_dev
ON        lib_dev.dev_type_id = "substring"(f_devs.load_id::text, '([0-9]+)'::text)::bigint;CREATE TABLE f_devs
             (
                          row_id     VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
                          load_id    VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
                          fact_value NUMERIC NULL,
                          CONSTRAINT f_devs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (row_id)
             );
```

QUERY PLAN is following:

```
 Hash Right Join  (cost=1367.27..29602029.56 rows=1 width=94) (actual time=29.582..880857.910 rows=2 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (((f_devs.row_id)::text = (t.calc_id)::text) AND ((f_devs.load_id)::text = (t.load_id)::text))
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1355.07..29577491.70 rows=1401465 width=8030) (actual time=17.861..856472.446 rows=140487536 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (("substring"((f_devs.load_id)::text, '([0-9]+)'::text))::bigint = lib_dev.dev_type_id)
        Filter: (ARRAY[(lib_dev.direction_id)::text, (f_devs.direction_id)::text, 'null'::text] && $3)
        CTE cte_rls
          ->  Function Scan on get_direction_rls get_direction_rls_1  (cost=0.26..0.27 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1.099..1.100 rows=1 loops=1)
        InitPlan 4 (returns $3)
          ->  CTE Scan on cte_rls cte_rls_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1.101..1.102 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on f_devs  (cost=0.00..7896986.60 rows=139817760 width=98) (actual time=1.544..68481.657 rows=140487536 loops=1)
       ->  Hash  (cost=1221.57..1221.57 rows=10657 width=16) (actual time=15.061..15.061 rows=10657 loops=1)
              Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 624kB
              ->  Seq Scan on isu_lib_deviations lib_dev  (cost=0.00..1221.57 rows=10657 width=16) (actual time=0.023..12.930 rows=10657 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=12.19..12.19 rows=1 width=91) (actual time=5.866..5.877 rows=2 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
        ->  Subquery Scan on t  (cost=1.14..12.19 rows=1 width=91) (actual time=5.788..5.870 rows=2 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.14..12.18 rows=1 width=6757) (actual time=5.787..5.861 rows=2 loops=1)
                    Filter: (ARRAY[(lib_dev_1.direction_id)::text, (f_tasks.direction_id)::text, 'null'::text] && $1)
                    CTE cte_rls
                      ->  Function Scan on get_direction_rls  (cost=0.26..0.27 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=2.773..2.773 rows=1 loops=1)
                    InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
                      ->  CTE Scan on cte_rls  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=2.774..2.775 rows=1 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using f_tasks_pkey on f_tasks  (cost=0.56..6.03 rows=2 width=96) (actual time=2.782..2.801 rows=2 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((row_id)::text = ANY ('{1066677788,1066677789}'::text[]))
                    ->  Index Scan using isu_lib_deviations_dev_type_id_idx on isu_lib_deviations lib_dev_1  (cost=0.29..2.91 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.029..0.030 rows=1 loops=2)
                          Index Cond: (dev_type_id = ("substring"((f_tasks.load_id)::text, '([0-9]+)'::text))::bigint)
Planning Time: 5.144 ms
Execution Time: 880858.389 ms
```

I wonder why hash join? I've got only 2 rows in total result. And when view vw_f_tasks is
launched with this condition

```sql
WHERE t.row_id IN ('1066677788','1066677789')
```

I've got only 2 rows joining to the big set of result. so it must be nested loop

Query in the beginning runs 15 minutes, but if I don't use 2 views and try to make another
equal query, it rans 1 second, because of nested loop:

```sql
SELECT f_tasks.row_id,
       f_tasks.calc_id,
       f_tasks.load_id,
       f.fact_value metric_value
FROM   f_tasks
       left join isu_lib_deviations archi
              ON archi.dev_type_id = "Substring"(f_tasks.load_id :: text,
                                     '([0-9]+)' :: text) ::
                                     bigint
       left join (SELECT f_devs.row_id,
                         f_devs.load_id,
                         f_devs.fact_value
                  FROM   f_devs
                         left join isu_lib_deviations archi
                                ON archi.dev_type_id = "Substring"(
                                                       f_devs.load_id :: text,
                                                       '([0-9]+)' :: text) ::
                                                       bigint) f
              ON f.row_id = f_tasks.calc_id
                 AND f.load_id = f_tasks.load_id
WHERE  f_tasks.row_id IN ( '1066677788', '1066677789' )
```

Comment: How do you think, maybe the problem is that there is no index on calc_id in table  f_tasks? And join f.row_id  = t.calc_id and f.load_id = t.load_id will use index?

Comment: Looks like this query plan is from a different query, get_direction_rls is not mentioned in your DDL nor SQL, only the query plan. Question: Do have a functional index using something like this: "substring"(f_devs.load_id::text, '([0-9]+)'::text)::bigint ? Your current index on f_devs.load_id can't used in this query

Comment: You right. It's because of function get_direction_rls. That's why table f_devs was read completely. I had to write in such way:
```SELECT t.row_id, t.calc_id, t.load_id, f.fact_value metric_value

FROM vw_f_tasks t

left join vw_f_devs f on f.row_id  = t.calc_id and f.load_id = any(array(select vft.load_id from vw_f_tasks vft where vft.row_id IN ('1066677788','1066677789')))

WHERE t.row_id IN ('1066677788','1066677789') ; ```

Comment: Pls check and post valid `DDL` - in both views: `ERROR: column lib_dev.direction_id does not exist`. Additionally the table `f_devs` has no column `dev_type_id` on which the index `ib_f_devs_dev_type_id` is defined.